# How do I fix the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function'

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7, ng-bootstrap

When I import NgbModule into app.module.ts, I get the following error:

```
    at ng-bootstrap.js:146
    at Module../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js (ng-bootstrap.js:148)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
```

I haven't used it anywhere in my code, I only included in my package.json and imported it in app.module.ts.

I saw on other post that when they had similar errors, it was because they were using the incorrect versions of ngbootstrap with angular and bootstrap, so I changed the versions but no change.  I also tried the NgbModule.forRoot() in my imports but it did not help.

Here is part of my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",    
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
```

and here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppNavbarComponent } from './app-navbar/app-navbar.component';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppNavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If I can get this to work, I am trying to implement the NgBoostrap dropdown component, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, as I stated earlier I changed the current versions bootstrap and ng-bootstrap in my package.json but that didn't work.  So I uninstalled ng-bootstrap with

```
npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --save
```

and installed version 4 with:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@4
```

Reloaded the page and everything worked!